# Guardar en one drive desde. NET

Tags: c#, net

Tengo la necesidad de mantener un histórico de ciertos documentos , mi solución inicial era copiarlos a una carpeta compartida desde .NEt, pero eso no parece muy seguro.Puedo hacer la carga de esos archivos a one drive utilizando .NET con c#? De ser así, me gustaría:(( documentación al respecto , ya he hecho una búsqueda libre y no he encontrado nada que satisfaga mis necesidades. Me disculpo si la pregunta es demasiado vaga.Gracias

Comment: Esto tal vez te funcione es un api de one drive: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

Comment: one drive tiene el poder de guardar historial, aunque por mi parte preferiría sharepoint si estuviera disponible

Comment: Exactamente que puedo hacer con sharepoints?sinceramente me he frustrado leyendo los proyectos de ejemplo de microsoft.Si pudieses sugerirme algo con sharepoints(tampoco sé algo de sharepoints,pero a lo mejor me resulte más claro),seria de agradecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy fácil con One Drive:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/

Cargar el fichero:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content

Obtener listado de versiones de tus documentos:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_versions

y como [Victor Perdomo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95802/victor-perdomo) ha mencionado aqui esta la sdk:
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

Comment: Me he puesto a leer la api que provee google,considero que es varias veces más simple,la recomiendo,muchas gracias por la documentación.